# How to assign row numbers to cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to make the columns be from 1 to 195, in order from least to greatest, so that if I make a mistake (say, I want to add an entry between row 28 and 29), I want Excel to order itself from 1 to 196.

*Example:*

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
__ I want to insert a new row here
7
8
```

and so on...

*Excel aligns itself to:*

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7 (The new row)
8
9
```

and so on...

Is there a function in Excel that allows me to do this?

What I mean is there's a column with numbers. How do I organize them in increasing order, so that if a row was added, the numbers would shift down into the next row and the numbers for that column would be in an increasing order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you are after, but if you want a cell containing a number dependent on its row, then use the

```
=row()
```

funtion.  If you insert a row, then this will automatically increment the numbers in the rows after the insert.

Comment: that's what I want. Is there a button for this?

Comment: Just type it into a cell exactly as above

Comment: No, what I mean is there's a column with numbers. How do I organize them in increasing order, so that if a row was added, the numbers would shift down into the next row and the numbers for that column would be in an increasing order?

Comment: Put `=row()` into each row instead of putting numbers in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make a table. Then just have the column sort ascending. It won't do it automatically though.  After you enter in a bunch of cells in that column, you'll have to tell Excel to sort ascending again.

Or you could just select the column and click Data, then Sort.

But then again, that's isn't what a spreadsheet is for.

What are you trying to create? What's the final result?